# Facebook Ads Api - add an adAccount to an existing AdAccountGroup without requesting approval of existing accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to add an adAccount to an existing AdAccountGroup using the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/AdAccountGroupID/adaccounts?account_ids=arrayofaccounts&access_token=...

the problem is that if I pass only the new account, then the group has only one account (the new one) and if I send an array with all current accounts and the new one it requests approval for all accounts

does anyone know how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: With the Facebook Business Manager do you still have a need for the ad account group?  Especially since system users cannot access the ad account group.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adaccountgroup/v2.2